# access onedrive from azure ML notebook script - 400 Client Error Tenant does not have a SPO license

Tags: azure, machine-learning, onedrive

im trying to access my onedrive from an azure ML script , both using same account ( though the azure one is personal while the onedrive one is work ) . The connection succeeds but then gives a 400 error...any idea why ?  thanks
----------------
Authenticated!
Client Error: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/root | Error Message: Tenant does not have a SPO license.

```
--------------
from O365 import Account

credentials = ('client id xxxx 6fb8a4', 'secret value xxxxx v6Hyoa2K')
account = Account(credentials,auth_flow_type='credentials',tenant_id='87xxxxx8-3db7f7',main_resource='myemail@email.com')

storage = account.storage()

if account.authenticate():
    print('Authenticated!')
    
my_drive = storage.get_default_drive() 
root_folder = my_drive.get_root_folder()

# iterate over the first 25 items on the root folder
for item in root_folder.get_items(limit=25):
    if item.is_folder:
        print(list(item.get_items(2))) # print the first two element on this folder.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Client Error: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/root | Error Message: Tenant does not have a SPO license.**

***The error you are getting for that you need to notice the couple of things.*** Please check the points stated in this [stackover flow reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46802055/tenant-does-not-have-a-spo-license/46869065#46869065) which says,

> `Office 365, Azure Active Directory, EMS (Enterprise Mobility Suite), personal Outlook, personal OneDrive, and other Microsoft cloud services` are all accessible through the developer portal or API known
> as Microsoft Graph. The API is free to use, but in order to access the
> data it hides, you must have those services, some of which may be free
> and others of which you may have to pay for.
>
> Regarding integrating Office 365 into your current tenant. I believe
> you used a Microsoft Account to join up for Azure. For that tenant,
> you can still buy or acquire Office 365. You may have to  add a
> new Azure AD user to your tenant (not a Microsoft Account) and give
> them company admin privileges. Whether it asks if you already have a
> tenant or account, login in with the AAD account you just generated.
> *You should then be able to sign up for Office 365. And there you have it an Azure AD tenant with both an Azure AND an Office 365
> subscription.*

**Solution :**  You must be using an Office 365 Home license for you azure ad tenant. For SharePoint Online you need an Office 365 Business account .

You need a ***license*** that include all the OneDrive service (Operation). So, recommendation is Office 365 Business Essentials which is the cheapest and has Microsoft Graph functionality - more than just upload/manipulate Excel files in OneDrive in future.

***So from the above conclusion, you can't use the Microsoft Graph API to access OneDrive data(read and upload) without having SharePoint Online (which only comes with the business licenses).***

**Reference:**

- [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59159530/tenant-does-not-have-a-spo-license-when-using-microsoft-graph-api-with-applicati) by Allen Wu

Comment: Thanks Venkatesen but I have this SharePoint License because I pay for O365 business account using my_account_email (work ). Is the Client_ID of the Azure ML script using my_account_email (personal )  should be pointing to my_account_email (work )? thanks again